# Audio Player Not Auto Playing?

Tags: flash, audio

I have scripted a basic Audio player and it plays when I hit the play button but it wont auto play..

```
<embed src="http://vipes.us/Gavin/GavinsPlayer.swf?autoplay=true&mp3=http://vipes.us/Gavin/testing.mp3&amp;autoplay=1bgcolor=ffffff&amp;loadingcolor=4c4c4c&amp;buttoncolor=4c4c4c" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="200" height="10" name="billy" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Theres the script to the audio player, and the example that it plays when you hit the PLAY button is here

> http://vipes.us/Gavin/GavinsPlayer.swf?autoplay=0&mp3=http://vipes.us/Gavin/testing.mp3&autoplay=0&bgcolor=ffffff&loadingcolor=000&buttoncolor=4c4c4c

Comment: why you are passing two autoplay variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you are passing two autoplay variables?
Try below,

```
<embed src="http://vipes.us/Gavin/GavinsPlayer.swf?mp3=http://vipes.us/Gavin/testing.mp3&amp;autoplay=1&bgcolor=ffffff&loadingcolor=4c4c4c&buttoncolor=4c4c4c" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="200" height="10" name="billy" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, And so sorry for late reply.